# JMeter proxy server in apache-jmeter-2.10 in NOT started, but in apache-jmeter-2.9 is started well

Tags: apache, jmeter

OS: Windows 7 32-bit
Java: jdk1.7.0_25

I have downloaded "apache-jmeter-2.10.zip" from http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi. I followed the PDF doc "http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf" for recording HTTP/HTTPS steps.

When I did the following step an error was occurred:
Return to HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder, and click the “Start” button at the bottom.

[image]

Console warning during starting JMeter (apache-jmeter-2.10):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to jmeter.bat (Windows): (for setting JAVA_HOME="path to JDK")

```
rem for example
set JAVA_HOME=C:\jdk1.7.0_25
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
```

See details on: https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/TestRecording210